# Value of $\frac{\cos 45}{\sec 30 + \operatorname{cosec} 30}$

Tags: trigonometry

I just put the values from the trignometric table to solve, but the answer is different in the answer book.

$$\frac{\cos 45}{\sec 30 + \operatorname{cosec} 30}$$

Comment: What is your answer? What is book's answer?

Comment: Degrees versus radians?

Comment: Using self-contained title in textstyle is highly recommended!

Comment: Book answer: $$\dfrac{3\sqrt 2 - sqrt 6}{8}$$

My answer: $$\dfrac{2\sqrt 3}{7\sqrt 2}$$

Comment: I can't figure out how you arrive at your solution. If you are interested and write your steps we will say you where is the mistake.

Comment: @mfl, I'm sorry, but it was a silly mistake made by me..when I matched my steps with user:amWhy's, I found that I have put the value of $cosec 30$ to sqrt(3)/2..Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\dfrac{\cos 45}{\sec 30 + \csc  30} = \frac{\cos 45}{\frac 1{\cos 30} + \frac 1{\sin 30}} = \frac{\frac {\sqrt 2}2}{\frac{2}{\sqrt 3} + 2} $$

$$= \frac{\frac {\sqrt 2}2}{\frac{2}{\sqrt 3} + 2} \cdot \frac{2\sqrt 3}{2\sqrt 3} = \frac{\sqrt 2\sqrt 3}{2\left(2+2\sqrt 3\right)}$$

$$=\frac{\sqrt 6}{4(1+\sqrt 3)}\cdot\frac{1 - \sqrt 3}{1-\sqrt 3} = \frac{\sqrt 6(1-\sqrt 3)}{4(1 - 3)} = \frac{\sqrt 6-3\sqrt 2}{-8}$$

$$ = \frac{3\sqrt 2-\sqrt 6}{8}$$

Comment: ThankYou...simple question, but I'm kinda weak at Trigonometry :p

Comment: You're welcome, Vivek.